# Java Discount Calculation

Tags: java

I'm new to coding hence the doubt. 
The main objective is to get the LeastPrice of items (including the discount).
The following code works fine but only shows least price ignoring discount. 
How to calculate discount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of logic error in your `getLeastPriceItem` function.

**Problem #1:**
`for(int i=1;i<item.length;i++)`

The first index should be 0 not 1. Otherwise you are not processing the first item.

**Problem #2:**
`if (item[i].getItemPrice() < min)`

You are not including the discount price for comparison.

Assuming discount is by whole number and not percentage then the code should be something like `double afterDiscount = item[i].getItemPrice() - item[i].getItemDiscount();`

**Problem #3:**
`public static double getLeastPriceItem`

Not so much of a problem but I will recommend returning the entity `Item` instead.

So here is my proposed solution;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item[] item= new Item[5];
        item[0] = new Item(1, "a", 100.0, 20.0);
        item[1] = new Item(2, "b", 80.0, 30.0);
        item[2] = new Item(3, "c", 300.0, 40.0);
        item[3] = new Item(4, "d", 400.0, 390.0);
        item[4] = new Item(5, "e", 500.0, 60.0);

        Item cheapest = getLeastPriceItem(item);
        System.out.println("Least item price: "+ cheapest.getItemPrice() + " with discount of: " + cheapest.getItemDiscount());
    }

    public static Item getLeastPriceItem(Item[] item)
    {
        double currMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Item cheapestItem = null;
        for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++)
        {
            double afterDiscount = item[i].getItemPrice() - item[i].getItemDiscount();
            if(afterDiscount < currMin)
            {
                currMin = afterDiscount;
                cheapestItem = item[i];
            }
        }
        return cheapestItem;
    }
```

**Output:**

> Least item price: 400.0 with discount of: 390.0

The algorithm here is to track the current cheapest item's value and also the cheapest item object. Loop through all of the items in the array and compare them accordingly, then return the cheapest item object.

Returning the item is a more elegant solution because once you figured out the instance of the cheapest object, you can do/print whatever you like from it's properties. E.g. finding how much discount value it has etc.

Comment: Ran the code using your proposed solution but getting the below ouput. 
    `0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    Curr least item price 1.7976931348623157E308
    Curr least item price 80.0
    Curr least item price 70.0
    Curr least item price 60.0
    Curr least item price 50.0
    Least item price 100.0`

Comment: @macboyme95 - apologise for the debug statements i got in there. I have since updated the solution to remove them and make those product's pricing more obvious instead of using 100.0 value for all prods. Also included the sample output to the solution.

Comment: Yeah. It ran correctly now. Just last query. What if the discount rates are in percentage?

Comment: Then you will have to work out the mathematical formula which is probably just the usual multiply and divide and replace this line `double afterDiscount = item[i].getItemPrice() - item[i].getItemDiscount();` with it. Will appreciate if you mark (the tick beside the solution) as answered for future users. Thank you!

Comment: How to display the final price `(After discount)`  eg. In your ouput the price should be `400-390=10`

Comment: @macboyme95 I would suggest adding a `afterDiscount()` method into the `Item` class. This method will do something like `return this.getItemPrice() - this.getItemDiscount();` That way your `getLeastPriceItem` method can use it and you can also call `item.afterDiscount() for the final price. Sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingPrice {

    private static double dis;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Item Name :");
        String itmName = s.next();

        System.out.println("Please Enter the Item No :");
        int itmNo = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please Enter the Item rate :");
        double rate = s.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please Enter the Item Quantity :");
        int quantity = s.nextInt();

        double nPrice;
        nPrice = rate * quantity; // nPrice means Net Price

        if (nPrice >= 1000 && nPrice < 2000)
            dis = 0.10 * nPrice;
        else
            if (nPrice >= 2000 && nPrice < 3000)
                dis = 0.15 * nPrice;
            else
                if (nPrice >=3000 && nPrice < 4000)
                    dis = 0.20 * nPrice;
                else
                    if (nPrice >= 5000)
                        dis = 0.25 * nPrice;

        double tPrice = nPrice - dis;
        double savings = nPrice - tPrice;
        double dPercent = (dis/nPrice) * 100;
        int eSavings = 0; // Extra Savings... I will use this for more practice..

        System.out.println("Item Number is :" + itmNo);
        System.out.println("Item Name is :" + itmName);
        System.out.println("Net price of the basket is :" + nPrice);
        System.out.println("Discount percentage is :" + dPercent + "%");
        System.out.println("Discount on the Basket is :" + dis);
        System.out.println("Extra savings on the basket :" + eSavings);
        System.out.println("Total savings on the basket is :" + savings);
        System.out.println("Total Price of Basket is :" + tPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a description/comments to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the code block where you compare prices for the min, you could just factor in the discount for each item.

Try replacing:

```
if (item[i].getItemPrice() < min)
```

with,

```
if (item[i].getItemPrice() * item[i].getItemDiscount() < min)
```

Hope that helps! It's been a while since I've used Java :)

Comment: It still doesnt work. Still ignoring discount price.